# Does Joomla have an api endpoint for cms ajax?

Tags: javascript, joomla, content-management-system, headless

I'm looking around Joomla documentation, and am having a difficult time locating any docs related to ajax calls for javascript angular app. I need to have Joomla as a CMS and get the data in json format.

Is this documented somewhere or can this not be done with Joomla?

Comment: https://docs.joomla.org/JSON_Responses_with_JResponseJson or https://docs.joomla.org/Generating_JSON_output

Answer (score 0):

create  a json view and a menu item (not included in menu modules) and use that url on you javascript objects;